# How do you calculate burns needed to land?

Tags: spacecraft, propulsion, landing

Assume I was landing a rocket and wanted to do calculations on how to correctly land. How do you determine at what time you fire the engine and at what power to successfully land on a predetermined landing spot? I am also wondering if you can calculate at what height you have to fire the engines to arrive smoothly on a landing pad on sea level. I am opening a space company named Pluto; and we will dramatically reduce the cost of space flight. Our 'Mini' rocket has 2 stages with a height of 52ft. Our highest mission will currently reach 30,000 ft. We are looking for ways to successfully land our spacecraft with no parachute and to perform a propulsive landing.

Comment: Welcome to the site @Kai, and I wish you luck on your venture. This question is extremely broad. Space-X, Blue Origin and other companies have been working on this problem for years, there's no way a single question would cover the subject.

Comment: @GdD while the engineering is undoubtedly complex, the math behind the burn is straightforward enough to be seen in mods for the game Kerbal Space Program (Referred in that community as a 'suicide burn' because to delay it for an instant would result in crashing on the surface). As such, the question is **on topic**, and not broad. I would be keen to know the maths myself, as I do not know the answer to this one.

Comment: The landing burn is nothing else than the launch - just backward in time and with a mass that increases instead of decreases.

Comment: @asdfex can you expand on that? Why does the mass increase?

Comment: @organic-marble What i meant is that if you record a launch and play it backwards it looks almost like a landing burn (and the same math can be employed). The only difference is as we run time backwards, the mass of he rocket increases as it gets higher. This essentially boils down to change the sign of $\Delta v$ in the formulas.

Comment: @asdfex for a real propulsive landing the mass would be decreasing so it's not clear to me how that helps at all.

Comment: @OrganicMarble It makes sense to me. Pretend your propellant has negative mass, calculate your burn from land to the appropriate suborbital trajectory and run that simulation backwards in time. You get a result that's equivalent to the landing burn. I suspect this symmetry only occurs on airless bodies, however.